# Cherokee web server with PHP can't connect to MSSQL

Tags: php, sql-server, webserver, cherokee

I have a Cherokee web server and I need to make work with PHP and SQL Server database. I've installed Freetds and php5-sybase.

Te problem is that Cherokee doesn't load the mssql.so module. It loads every other module it has odbc.so, pdo.so, pdo_dblib.so,pdo_odbc.so, suhosin.so but no mssql.so.

I try to connect with php cli and it connects Ok. I tried to install an apache in another port and also works and connect ok to SQL Server.

Cherokee always return "Call to undefined function mssql_connect()" on cherokee.error log, is because the module haven't been loaded.  phpinfo() doesn't show any mssql module load.

If someone with Cherokee experience can help me I'll be very gratufull. I supose that in some way I can add manualy the module to Cherokee.

Cheers.